# HTML Canvas, How to stop program until click on canvas is received?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm currently working on a game in HTML Canvas. No outside dependencies. It involves the HTML Element Canvas, and almost nothing else. The game has no actively changing screen, because it is a business simulator. I am not new to game development or programming, but I am new to Canvas game programming. My problem is I want to do everything through canvas with no outside elements. I made my own buttons within canvas, and am trying to check to see where the click was registered only after the program was clicked, because I don't want the game constantly checking mouse position without a click to have occurred. Do Event Listeners only work if the JavaScript is still running? Is there anyway to write in the main game loop, something along the lines of in psuedocode

```
while !exit
     if(input)
        update();
        render();
```

Do event listeners not work explicitly like this, or do I have to write it like

`while !exit
      sleep(16.67);`

In this situation the event listener is just actively checking for input, but not explicitly, with a function that updates whenever a click is recieved?

Is this how canvas works? Do event listeners just constantly check as long as the program is running?

Any Feedback on how to go about doing this would be greatly appreciated. I'll be willing to answer any further questions to help find an answer. Thanks.

Comment: _“Do Event Listeners only work if the JavaScript is still running?”_ – no. JavaScript is (under any normal circumstances) not “constantly running” in the first place. _“Is there anyway to write in the main game loop […]”_ – no, such a loop would be the wrong approach to begin with, it will block any interaction with the page (for a while, and then the browser will ask the user if they want to abort this long running and blocking script). I think you need to go research some more basics of how one works with JS and events in the context of a web page, your question as it is is just too broad.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not need to be looping to be listening for events. So a game loop is useless for a type of game like this that is not actively rendering. I was lead to believe that event listeners weren't working, because I used the syntax `canvas.addEventListener("click", onClick());`

This does not work, because if you specifically write the parentheses after the function name, it calls the function and there is no event listener added.

So for a game like this, you would want to hook the event listener (without the parentheses) to an update function, and not use a loop.